# Remove proximity alerts when uninstalling app

Tags: android, gps, alert, proximity

I have a problem with proximity alerts on Android.

Here's what I'm doing in my app

1. Fetch list of locations from server.
2. Add proximity alerts of these locations (now GPS icon shows in status bar).
3. When user enters the area launch my app activity.

Problem is that, when I uninstall my app with proximity alerts added it still shows GPS icon in status bar. User can turn off all proximity alerts in app but it doesn't solve my problem. I also now that it's impossible to do anything during uninstall process. Any ideas?

//EDIT:

Only way to get rid of GPS icon after app uninstall is to restart the device.

Comment: "Problem is that, when I uninstall my app with proximity alerts added it still shows GPS icon in status bar" -- if you are seeing this on the emulator, this is perfectly normal, as the emulator does not get rid of the GPS icon once it has been added to the status bar.

Comment: I'm aware of that but problem exists on real device.

Answer (score 0):

[Report bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=User%20bug%20report) to Android developers. LocationManager should handle such use case (this case is easy to forget and apparently Android developers forgot about that).

As a workaround you can try to create a service which will exist as long as you need proximity alert. I'm hoping that service is gracefully closed on removal and not just killed. In such case you will remove proximity alert. You have to try it to be sure that this is good solution.

Comment: No, when application is being uninstalled even service's method onDestroy() is not called, so I can't do anything. And it suck, because proximity alert is draining battery.